# How can I identify the location of the first word in all caps ignoring words less than 5 characters[R]?

Tags: r, regex, parsing, text

I want to identify the location of the first word in all caps *ignoring words less than 5 characters* in R.

Example data:

```
myvec <- c("FILT Words Here before CAPITALS words here after","Words OUT ALLCAPS words MORECAPS words after","Mywords PRE Before CAPLET more words after the capital Letters CAPLETTERS","PRE CAP letters SPLIT here not before")
```

Desired results:

```
desired_first_word_over4char_caps <- c(5,3,4,4)
desired_first_word_over4char <- c("CAPITALS","ALLCAPS","CAPLET","SPLIT")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions:

```
> strsplit(myvec, " ") |> lapply(grep, pattern = "^[A-Z]{5,}$") |> sapply(min)
[1] 5 3 4 4
```

```
> strsplit(myvec, " ") |> lapply(grep, pattern = "^[A-Z]{5,}$", value=TRUE) |> sapply(head, 1)
[1] "CAPITALS" "ALLCAPS"  "CAPLET"   "SPLIT"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
words <- strsplit(myvec, ' ')
desired_first_word_over4char_caps <- vapply(words, \(x) grep('^[A-Z]{5,}$', x)[1L], integer(1L))
desired_first_word_over4char <- mapply(`[`, words, desired_first_word_over4char_caps)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner that creates a named vector with words/positions, i.e.

```
 mapply(match, stringr::str_extract(myvec, '\\b[A-Z]{5,}\\b'), strsplit(myvec, ' '))

CAPITALS  ALLCAPS   CAPLET    SPLIT 
       5        3        4        4
```

You can bring the output to user desired format, i.e.

```
res <- mapply(match, stringr::str_extract(myvec, '\\b[A-Z]{5,}\\b'), strsplit(myvec, ' '))

names(res)
#[1] "CAPITALS" "ALLCAPS"  "CAPLET"   "SPLIT"   

unname(res)
#[1] 5 3 4 4

data.frame(position = res)
#         position
#CAPITALS        5
#ALLCAPS         3
#CAPLET          4
#SPLIT           4
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses `strcapture` to create a data frame with column `char` and then adds a length column, `char_caps`.  No packages are used.

```
myvec |>
  strcapture("\\b([A-Z]{5,})\\b", x = _, data.frame(char = character(0))) |>
  transform(char_caps = nchar(char))
##       char char_caps
## 1 CAPITALS         8
## 2  ALLCAPS         7
## 3   CAPLET         6
## 4    SPLIT         5
```